# Function condition being executed without condition being met

Tags: c, function, return

I declare my variable

```
int exceedLimit = 0;
```

I call a function

```
    compareLimit(selectChannel,exceedLimit);
```

This function checks the current value of select channel and if it exceeds the current set limit (high limit is set to 100, and low limit to 50). by default it should not be triggered until the user changes some values.

```
int compareLimit (int channelID, int isLimitExceeded)
{

if (temperatureChannel[channelID].currentTemperature > temperatureChannel[channelID].highLimit || temperatureChannel[channelID].currentTemperature < temperatureChannel[channelID].lowLimit)
     isLimitExceeded = 2;      
else
    isLimitExceeded = 1;

return isLimitExceeded;

}
```

Now here's the problem in the next line of code....In the previous function i returned isLimitExceeded, and then i try to match that returned value to determine if the alarm state should trigger ot not. this if statement is written right after compareLimit

```
  if (exceedLimit = 2)
             logSubsystem();
```

When i run this program, my exceedLimit immediately triggers and my logsubsystem function is called...but how can that be since i declared `exceedLimit = 0` at the beginning of my cpp file??

Comment: Classic mistake: `exceedLimit = 2` needs one more `=`.

Comment: `if (exceedLimit = 2)` -> `if (exceedLimit == 2)`

Comment: [This is why I'm voting down and for closure.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions)

Comment: exceedLimit ==2 doesn't fix my problem though H2C03...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if (exceedLimit = 2)` should be `if (exceedLimit == 2)`.

`if (exceedLimit = 2)` Here you're assigning the value *2* to `exceedLimit` and not comparing its value to *2*.

Note that the expression of the assignment *returns the assigned value*, in this case `if(exceedLimit = 2)` will be always *true*, that's why the code below the *if-statement* is always executed.

Comment: If you had the warning level set high enough on most decent modern compilers, it would have warned you about this.  The old school way of avoiding the problem was reversing it.  i.e. if (2 = exceedLimit) will pick up the error if you don't use ==.

Comment: even if i do that it immediately goes into alarm when i startup the program. The previous poster who posted an answer suggested writing it as: exceedlimit = compareLimit(selectChannel,exceedLimit) and then using the double equals as an equivalent operator